# Broadcast a message with out creating any session or channel or connection in Blackberry messenger?

Tags: blackberry, bb-messenger

I am developing an application which integrates with BBM.
My requirement is that when I click on a Broadcast button that the user-entered message should go to all Blackberry messenger contacts.
It should not open any contact picker or Blackberry messenger default screen.
The message should go to all my Blackberry messenger contacts which are already add to my default blackberry messenger.

I am using BBM SDK v1.2 for BlackBerry Java OS 6 
work on OS7 , bold 9900 , BBM 6.0.0.129.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Find the following link which will help how to work with bbm...

it will show all the process to establish connection BBM

[BBM LINK](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/bbm/1.2.0api/index.html)